# Postfix notify send

Tags: postfix

**My scenario**

I'm writing a website that uses local postfix to send email to users. For any email I'm going to send I need to know if postfix has successfully delivered it (to the next-hop), or not.

**What I've done so far**

I correctly configured the execution of a script in case the email is bounced. To achieve this I send email with something like "info+2493@mydomain" as envelope sender address, where 2493 is the unique identifier of my mail, and configured a transport entry for info@mydomain which use a ad-hoc relay (in master.cf) that executes my script. Good

**My question**

How can I configure the execution of a script just like I did for bounced email for successfully delivered email instead?

And what other possibilities exist for a mail being sent besides bounced and delivered which I should care about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For knowing status of mail delivery, [postfix use DSN](http://www.postfix.org/DSN_README.html#cli) as state in [RFC 3464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464). The documentation states there are 3 delivery status

- Success (server accept the message)
- Delayed (server can't deliver right now, but it will try again)
- Failure (server can't deliver it, bounced back to sender)

If you send email via `sendmail` (for example with [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) in PHP), the default state is postfix will notify you in case there is failure or delay. If you want to be notified if message is successfully sent, add parameter `-N delay,failure,success` in your sendmail command. This feature documented in [Postfix DSN Support](http://www.postfix.org/DSN_README.html#cli) and [SENDMAIL(1)](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html).

**UPDATE**

To distinguish success delivery and failure, you can parsing the attachment of `DSN email`, especially in `Delivery report` section.

Here the snippet of failure delivery

```
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; example.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 3gPtcL5lvrzDFBC
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; sender@example.com
Arrival-Date: Fri,  9 May 2014 08:04:50 +0700 (WIT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; nonexist@example.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;nonexist@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: dns; example.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 <nonexist@example.com>: Recipient address
    rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table
```

Here the snippet of success delivery

```
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; www.example.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 5936DF75D4
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; sender@example.com
Arrival-Date: Thu,  8 May 2014 22:58:40 +0700 (WIT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; myrecipient@example.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;myrecipient@example.com
Action: relayed
Status: 2.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; delivery via dovecot: delivered via dovecot service
```

Comment: Good. I can successfully be notified back. But now with a "pipe" in master.cf to execute my script I cannot distinguish the delivery status (success, failed, delayed).. I don't see any suitable ${parameter} in "man pipe". If this is not feasible I will fallback to automatically check the whole DSN email.

Comment: @Jack Looks like you can't add parameter in your pipe program. Good luck with parsing the email body. See updated answer.